# Songs like "Mile High Club" and "Skank Tank"

Tags: electronic-music, similar-artists, style

For the longest time I have wanted to find music similar to these two songs, but I have never known the name of the style, or any other way of finding more:

- [Just Cause 2 - Mile High Club](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XyZUEka5F0)

  - View comments for song info in MusicBrainz.org, Last.fm & RateYourMusic.com
- [Steven Young & David Felton - Skank Tank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrunzHkD2m4)

  - View comments for song info in MusicBrainz.org, Last.fm & Spotify

Maybe someone here can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Spotify.... & don't get caught up in what a 'genre' is called. Music is music, enjoy it.

Comment: @Bebs: Spotify didn't help very much. Looking up the Skant Tank's artist's other songs turned up almost nothing (Mile High Club is part of an OST for a videogame so I doubt the author has done many tracks like that one). Spotalike and moretrackslikethis failed. Similarsong is unavailable. Pandora is unavailable where I live. Musicbrainz lists both [Skank Tank](https://musicbrainz.org/recording/7ac18268-b4c6-4014-acfb-9130b5c66937) and [Mile High Club](https://musicbrainz.org/recording/f395ca4c-ef49-4be0-aae8-8d309f2ac0e3) but I don't know what to do with that info.

Comment: @Bebs: In last.fm: [Skank Tank](https://www.last.fm/music/Steven+Young+&+David+Felton/_/Skank+Tank+(Original+Mix)) and [Mile High Club](https://www.last.fm/music/Just+cause+2/_/Mile+High+Club). Rateyourmusic only has [Just Cause 2's OST](https://rateyourmusic.com/release/album/mats_lundgren_anders_ehlin/just_cause_2__music_to_blow_s__t_up_by/).

Comment: Here is [Skank Tank in Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/6PqxcIMH7pLlMLq0JXz1r3) also

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact match, but "dubstep" is a popular recent musical subgenre that combines electronic dance music focused around similar kind of scratchy/rumbly synthesized bass line.  That might be your best starting place for finding similar songs.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of dubsteb, but have not yet delved much into it, other than Skrillex (his style is different from what I'm looking for here though). I'll probably do that and see what I find.

Answer (score 0):

What I hear: bpm - 90-120 bpm, lateral march for thrashing, aggressive bass that is distorted, no particularly driving melody lines from the tenor or treble ends and reliance on dark ambience.

The music I am hearing is EBM grooves.  Most EBM is less cinematic than what you have there (given that what you are listening to is a videogame soundtrack) but it might do the trick.  It's also a bit faster at regular speed.  At regular speed.  Pitch it down 10% and you have what you are looking for.  Not many playlists out there that don't mix it with other sounds so you might enjoy the potpourri in these mixes.

The following mixtape has a playlist for you to peruse.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc0i_wyY3_A

Answer (score -1):

These two songs are pretty rad:

- [Psy Trance - Electronic Pulsation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbDxHDfEoeA)
- [Warp Brothers vs. Aquagen - Phatt Bass (Blood Rave Blade 2016 Bootleg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aM_DNt7dN0E)

Comment: While these songs are close to what I'm looking form, I asked for some way to independently find similar songs, for example style or musician names. I see these are trance songs so it kinda helps in that way. Even so, thanks for the suggestions, I liked Phatt Bass very much!